# Unknown column in where clause after server change

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I have a somewhat hellish query (legacy database) that yields me a "column not found" error. It looks like this (VERY simplified):

```
select somecolumn as name,
...
...,
(select sum(someothercolumn) from table where somecolumn = name)
from table
where (conditions)
```

The odd thing about this is that it started happening only when we changed the server. Before we moved our database everything worked fine with the query. The old MySQL version was 5.6.14. The new server is running 5.7.9.

Is this a problem with the MySQL version? Is it probably some setting that changed its default value for 5.7? What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the subquery throwing the error?

Comment: Can you post the `WHERE` clause and the table definition?

Comment: I have no idea who's throwing the error, Rahul. MySQL simply shows me a dialog with the error.

Comment: I was able to rewrite my affected queries, at some cost to legibility, but opened a bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549

Answer (score 1):

Could you please use alias for each table in this query? and don't forget to insert the alias letter before each column.
**example:**

select r.somecolumn as name,

...

,(select sum(s.someothercolumn) from table as s where s.somecolumn = r.name)

from table r

where (r.conditions)

Comment: Using alias it would become something like:

`select a.somecolumn as name,
...
...,
(select sum(someothercolumn) from table as b where b.somecolumn = a.name)
from table as a
where (conditions)`

do you think that would solve the issue?

Comment: Also, this does not answer my original question, which is why it used to work in 5.6 but it stopped working on 5.7

Comment: yes and put the alias b for sum(someothercolumn), i faced this error once and it worked by putting alias for tables, but can you post the error to make sure that this is the solution?

Comment: It's an unknown column error. Using aliases solves the problem, but that only solves the practical problem. The question of why it used to work in the previous version and it stopped on this

Answer (score 0):

if you have mysql 5.7.9 in your server, you must know that have a bug in that version
try using mysql 5.7.11 to solve this problem.